# Why are the parent's methods still alive after child's destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, race-condition

I don't understand why the '''execute''' function of the Parent class is run. I feel like there are two instances: one for the parent class, one for the child class, but why? Indeed, this program is printing "1 Parent", as i expected "1 Child" or "0 Parent". If i uncomment the delay line, the output will be "1 Child".

I know there is a race condition in this program. This program was only made to understand the working principle of the inheritance in a multithreaded environment.

Thank you !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

class Parent
{
public:
    std::thread myThread;
    int a;
    Parent() {
        this->myThread = std::thread();
        this->a = 0;
    }
    void start()
    {
        this->myThread = std::thread(&Parent::execute, this);
    }
    virtual void execute() {
        std::cout << a << " Parent" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Parent() {
        while(!this->myThread.joinable());
        this->myThread.join();
    }

};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() {
        this->a = 1;
    }
    void execute() override {
        std::cout << a << " Child" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Child() {

    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Init" << std::endl;
    Child * chld = new Child();
    chld->start();
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
    std::cout << "Delete" << std::endl;
    delete chld;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Parent::execute()` still calls the parent's function.

Comment: Not always, if you put a delay between the start and the delete, you will call the ``Child::execute()`` function

Comment: Threading plays no rule here. If your write `Parent::execute` you explicitly tell which function to call instead of letting the runtime resolve the virtual function call.

Comment: I have seen exactly the same question yesterday but it seems it was deleted. I also explained that it's a reace condition because of Child deletion.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Try to execute the function with the delay I commented, it will execute the Child function because of the function override.

Comment: My guess, is that it's just undefined behavior.

Comment: If you uncomment the delay function, you're just _guaranteeing_ Undefined Behaviour instead of gambling on the scheduling.

Comment: It is fully independend, which function you call. You delete an object on which a other thread has a ( dangling ) pointer on. This is simply undefined behavior and a bug. The rest is a question of vtable pointer construction/deletion. But as said, these are side effects of an illegal program.

Comment: The weird thing is that it looks like there is an instance of the Parent class after the destruction of the "chld" object.

Comment: Only if you don't look very hard. The code explicitly calls the `Parent::execute` method via static dispatch, and the _function_ still exists even if the object it's called on no longer does. If the destructor set `a=0xDEADBEEF`, then maybe that's what the execute function would print (although you'd still have a bug, and it would also be a data race)

Comment: That loop in the destructor is weird. It blocks the destructor until someone has created a thread, but the object that holds the thread is in the process of being destroyed. What is this supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code exhibits the Undefined behavior (in your case resulting in `Parent::execute` call) because of the race condition between thread creation and `Child` object destruction. To fix it, you can define  proper start and stop methods in your `Parent` class and call `stop` in `Child` destructor to prevent it from being destroyed before thread joins.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(): myThread_() {
        std::cout << "Parent CTor" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    bool start()
    {
        std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
        if (myThread_.joinable()) {
            std::cout << "already started" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        myThread_ = std::thread([this]() {
            execute();
        });
        return true;
    }
    bool stop() {
        std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;
        if (!myThread_.joinable()) {
            std::cout << "not started" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        myThread_.join();
        return true;
    }
    virtual void execute() = 0;

private:
    std::thread myThread_;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() {
        std::cout << "Child CTor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Child() override {
        stop();
    }
    void execute() override {
        std::cout << "Child::execute()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Init" << std::endl;
    Child * chld = new Child();
    chld->start();
    std::cout << "Delete" << std::endl;
    delete chld;
    return 0;
}
```

I defined `Parent::execute` as abstract because probably you don't want it to be called at all and in case of another bug, at least you can get

```
terminate, pure virtual method called
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program has undefined behavior which means "everything can happen".

You start a new thread which hold a pointer ( this ) to an object. This thread will later call a virtual method which means it needs to use data from the object it points to. The vtable pointer itself is some kind of data of the class. Because you delete your object from the other thread, the pointer ( this ) is simply pointing to a destructed object and accessing data ( vtable ) from an deleted object is undefined behavior.

Your observation is depending on the compiler implementation and maybe also on optimizing level. It is possible, that your compiler rewinds during deconstruction the vtable pointer down to the base class pointer. And as the memory of the object is not overridden from any other content ( which is even undefined! ) you can observe a call to the base function after destruction. But this is nothing you can rely on, as it is not allowed at all to use any object after destruction IF you use data members of the object which here is the vtable pointer.

In a short: Your code contains a bug and everything can happen as it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing whatsoever to do with threads. You can reproduce the whole thing - including Undefined Behaviour - synchronously.

Single-threaded version of your classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Parent
{
public:
    int a;
    Parent() : a(0) {}
    virtual ~Parent() {}

    virtual void execute() {
        std::cout << a << " Parent" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() {
        a = 1;
    }
    void execute() override {
        std::cout << a << " Child" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and the single-threaded test cases demonstrating exactly the same behaviour:

```
int main()
{
    Child c;

    std::cout << "=== automatic lifetime ===\n";
    std::cout << "virtual dispatch: ";
    c.execute();
    std::cout << "explicit static dispatch: ";
    c.Parent::execute();

    std::cout << "=== dynamic lifetime ===\n";
    Child *pc = new Child;
    std::cout << "virtual dispatch: ";
    pc->execute();
    std::cout << "explicit static dispatch: ";
    pc->Parent::execute();

    std::cout << "=== undefined behaviour ===\n";
    delete pc;
    std::cout << "explicit static dispatch: ";
    pc->Parent::execute();
    std::cout << "virtual dispatch: ";
    pc->execute();
}
```

The last two output statements are swapped, because the last one crashed when I ran it (the penultimate is still UB, but happened not to crash)

```
=== automatic lifetime ===
virtual dispatch: 1 Child
explicit static dispatch: 1 Parent
=== dynamic lifetime ===
virtual dispatch: 1 Child
explicit static dispatch: 1 Parent
=== undefined behaviour ===
explicit static dispatch: 1 Parent
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: That's not really the same, as the object is not destroyed  in my code, because the main thread is waiting the second thread to join. Am I wrong ?

Comment: _If_ the Child destructor has already executed _before_ the thread is scheduled, then the method is called on an object whose dynamic type has been rolled back to Parent, while the Parent destructor is blocked. Is that the case you're interested in? Because in that case, you have a Parent object whose `a` still has the value `1` it was given by the Child constructor. The threading is still irrelevant because you can see this behaviour by calling an overridden virtual method from the base class destructor.